# Can I get some assistance with my iOS crash log?

Tags: ios, logging, crash

I have an app that is crashing on some refurbished iOS tablet devices.  Works fine elsewhere, I cannot recreate on other devices, but when I click 1 particular button on these devices.  I am attaching the crash report below, can someone help with understanding what the problem may be? Alternatively I need to ascertain whether it is due to the device or whether it is due to my code... any help?
TIA
Al

Full Crash Report:

```
{"app_name":"myAPPUS","timestamp":"2018-12-19 09:30:47.25 -0500","app_version":"2.13","slice_uuid":"43b980dc-7355-302d-b766-b768d879c7c0","adam_id":1244257222,"build_version":"1.0","bundleID":"ie.myAPPsupport.myAPPus","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)","incident_id":"7FB487F7-F26D-4AC8-A47F-4061EF9B11AD","name":"myAPPUS"}
Incident Identifier: 7FB487F7-F26D-4AC8-A47F-4061EF9B11AD
CrashReporter Key:   ed1580f8bcf2ad3fefcb752d391fab4310698734
Hardware Model:      iPad5,1
Process:             myAPPUS [190]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/myAPPUS
Identifier:          ie.myAPPsupport.myAPPus
Version:             1.0 (2.13)
AppStoreTools:       10B61
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ie.myAPPsupport.myAPPus [304]


Date/Time:           2018-12-19 09:30:47.1265 -0500
Launch Time:         2018-12-19 09:30:39.8137 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010038be00
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [190]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   myAPPUS                         0x000000010038be00 0x10037c000 + 65024
1   myAPPUS                         0x000000010038ba0c 0x10037c000 + 64012
2   Foundation                      0x00000001b571c85c 0x1b5617000 + 1071196
3   Foundation                      0x00000001b5670684 0x1b5617000 + 366212
4   Foundation                      0x00000001b56393c8 0x1b5617000 + 140232
5   Foundation                      0x00000001b571c85c 0x1b5617000 + 1071196
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b571bdc0 0x1b5617000 + 1068480
7   Foundation                      0x00000001b5628fc0 0x1b5617000 + 73664
8   Foundation                      0x00000001b567ec64 0x1b5617000 + 425060
9   myAPPUS                         0x0000000100391500 0x10037c000 + 87296
10  myAPPUS                         0x0000000100391364 0x10037c000 + 86884
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b46da484 0x1b4679000 + 398468
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b467c6d8 0x1b4679000 + 14040
13  myAPPUS                         0x0000000100410db8 0x10037c000 + 609720
14  myAPPUS                         0x0000000100470f6c 0x10037c000 + 1003372
15  myAPPUS                         0x0000000100470804 0x10037c000 + 1001476
16  myAPPUS                         0x000000010040b048 0x10037c000 + 585800
17  myAPPUS                         0x000000010040b3ec 0x10037c000 + 586732
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001e1c6fc14 0x1e117d000 + 11480084
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001e1c6fe78 0x1e117d000 + 11480696
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001e1a70cd0 0x1e117d000 + 9387216
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001e1a5eccc 0x1e117d000 + 9313484
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001e1a8dfa0 0x1e117d000 + 9506720
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2f7a8 0x1b4b84000 + 702376
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2a43c 0x1b4b84000 + 681020
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2a9dc 0x1b4b84000 + 682460
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2a1cc 0x1b4b84000 + 680396
27  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b6ea1584 0x1b6e96000 + 46468
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001e1a65054 0x1e117d000 + 9338964
29  myAPPUS                         0x000000010038655c 0x10037c000 + 42332
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b46eabb4 0x1b46ea000 + 2996

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bece8 0x1b48b0000 + 60648

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bece8 0x1b48b0000 + 60648

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bece8 0x1b48b0000 + 60648

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bece8 0x1b48b0000 + 60648

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bece8 0x1b48b0000 + 60648

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b482bed0 0x1b4814000 + 98000
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b482b3a8 0x1b4814000 + 95144
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2fbc4 0x1b4b84000 + 703428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2aa60 0x1b4b84000 + 682592
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2a1cc 0x1b4b84000 + 680396
5   Foundation                      0x00000001b561f404 0x1b5617000 + 33796
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b561f2b0 0x1b5617000 + 33456
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001e1b52808 0x1e117d000 + 10311688
8   Foundation                      0x00000001b57521ac 0x1b5617000 + 1290668
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb2ac 0x1b48b0000 + 45740
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb20c 0x1b48b0000 + 45580
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48becf4 0x1b48b0000 + 60660

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bece8 0x1b48b0000 + 60648

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bece8 0x1b48b0000 + 60648

Thread 9 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b4839948 0x1b4814000 + 153928
1   myAPPUS                         0x0000000100496880 0x10037c000 + 1157248
2   myAPPUS                         0x000000010048dae8 0x10037c000 + 1121000
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb2ac 0x1b48b0000 + 45740
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb20c 0x1b48b0000 + 45580
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48becf4 0x1b48b0000 + 60660

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bece8 0x1b48b0000 + 60648

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b482bed0 0x1b4814000 + 98000
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b482b3a8 0x1b4814000 + 95144
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2fbc4 0x1b4b84000 + 703428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2aa60 0x1b4b84000 + 682592
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2a1cc 0x1b4b84000 + 680396
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2af68 0x1b4b84000 + 683880
6   CoreMotion                      0x00000001ba677368 0x1ba5fb000 + 508776
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb2ac 0x1b48b0000 + 45740
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb20c 0x1b48b0000 + 45580
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48becf4 0x1b48b0000 + 60660

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b482bed0 0x1b4814000 + 98000
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b482b3a8 0x1b4814000 + 95144
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2fbc4 0x1b4b84000 + 703428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2aa60 0x1b4b84000 + 682592
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b4c2a1cc 0x1b4b84000 + 680396
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001b524b834 0x1b524a000 + 6196
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b57521ac 0x1b5617000 + 1290668
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb2ac 0x1b48b0000 + 45740
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb20c 0x1b48b0000 + 45580
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48becf4 0x1b48b0000 + 60660

Thread 13 name:  RLMRealm notification listener
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b483891c 0x1b4814000 + 149788
1   Realm                           0x0000000100b3eca8 0x100b2c000 + 76968
2   Realm                           0x0000000100b3fe2c 0x100b2c000 + 81452
3   Realm                           0x0000000100b3fdb4 0x100b2c000 + 81332
4   Realm                           0x0000000100b3ff64 0x100b2c000 + 81764
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb2ac 0x1b48b0000 + 45740
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48bb20c 0x1b48b0000 + 45580
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b48becf4 0x1b48b0000 + 60660

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000101ed8000   x1: 0x0000000281651560   x2: 0x0000000000000002   x3: 0x00000001b486eb2c
    x4: 0x0000000000000064   x5: 0x0000000000000064   x6: 0x000000016fa81408   x7: 0x000000016fa81498
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x0000000000000154  x10: 0x0000000000000073  x11: 0x00000000000007fb
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x00000000e6471000  x14: 0x00000000000000e2  x15: 0x0000000080000000
   x16: 0x0000000066400000  x17: 0x00000001016fff8c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000001
   x20: 0x000000028181e440  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000281651560  x23: 0x0000000000000008
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001eba78000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000001eba78000
   x28: 0x000000010057e880   fp: 0x000000016fa81c70   lr: 0x000000010038bcf4
    sp: 0x000000016fa81be0   pc: 0x000000010038be00 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x10037c000 - 0x10052bfff myAPPUS arm64  <43b980dc7355302db766b768d879c7c0> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/myAPPUS
0x1005cc000 - 0x100603fff AlamofireImage arm64  <bc7f5afe50323f2dbe20f8c2372e5aeb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/AlamofireImage.framework/AlamofireImage
0x10066c000 - 0x1006cffff dyld arm64  <fc36be383ccf330abe42940868e68937> /usr/lib/dyld
0x10073c000 - 0x1007affff Alamofire arm64  <cf84bffea7f436f0b753b3b63d16adf3> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
0x100884000 - 0x10088ffff AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator arm64  <bca356918f063c959e2a82e11e563a7c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator.framework/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator
0x1008a8000 - 0x1008b3fff AlamofireObjectMapper arm64  <df92dafe461230b8a4a434a1e8ee6eff> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/AlamofireObjectMapper.framework/AlamofireObjectMapper
0x1008cc000 - 0x10090bfff CryptoSwift arm64  <574bcd048e7734a09402fd08cec1a4f6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift
0x100980000 - 0x10099bfff EZAudio arm64  <9374a959d2333de4a3bad1b769fd3ef8> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/EZAudio.framework/EZAudio
0x1009cc000 - 0x1009d3fff HexColors arm64  <e4a9cef1b9393a79aa6b56ce7ceb504b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/HexColors.framework/HexColors
0x1009e4000 - 0x100a1ffff KeychainAccess arm64  <775390e3b3ba33b0b09b909e6cb38b3e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess
0x100a58000 - 0x100a63fff MBCircularProgressBar arm64  <8e722b53a19b3fc8b18fc02e18b3c191> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/MBCircularProgressBar.framework/MBCircularProgressBar
0x100a74000 - 0x100aaffff ObjectMapper arm64  <8d260b8f732a39abab14e97140618b9b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper
0x100b04000 - 0x100b0ffff Reachability arm64  <6d05a784d1703cc88723c03e8fd34536> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability
0x100b2c000 - 0x100ebbfff Realm arm64  <0446a5b53c083d5ab53499e59bc948d9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm
0x1011e0000 - 0x101227fff RealmSwift arm64  <648816e8c5fc3c3fa27296b28b0b7b6b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
0x1012e4000 - 0x101303fff SSZipArchive arm64  <d9127243ffd039d9a7ca5017d0bb94b2> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/SSZipArchive.framework/SSZipArchive
0x10131c000 - 0x10132ffff SVProgressHUD arm64  <b6690a2e16443d1985808980a2c9a4e8> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/SVProgressHUD.framework/SVProgressHUD
0x10134c000 - 0x101353fff TPCircularBuffer arm64  <5aeba16e1f8e3301a233568d07b0e269> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/TPCircularBuffer.framework/TPCircularBuffer
0x101360000 - 0x10137bfff UICircularProgressRing arm64  <49fd1bd502ee3d9190ac8793e2da81fa> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/UICircularProgressRing.framework/UICircularProgressRing
0x1013b0000 - 0x1013bbfff UIScrollView_InfiniteScroll arm64  <bb7be200e0ea372288f9203a920cf62c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/UIScrollView_InfiniteScroll.framework/UIScrollView_InfiniteScroll
0x1013cc000 - 0x1013e7fff Zip arm64  <1c0964823aff36f2a184bf30d329cf76> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/Zip.framework/Zip
0x10140c000 - 0x10141ffff libswiftAVFoundation.dylib arm64  <4df0db0d316f3a9980489bb2fa0c0aaf> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
0x101434000 - 0x10173ffff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <3db343d471023b338565df200cc0197e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x1019ec000 - 0x1019f3fff libswiftCoreAudio.dylib arm64  <54a77d22fa5739a2812aedc0c3e099fe> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
0x101a04000 - 0x101a0bfff libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib arm64  <81f66e04bab133feb3369b4162a68afc> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
0x101a14000 - 0x101a27fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <f1f2287fb5153a28beea12ec2d547bf8> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x101a48000 - 0x101a4ffff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <9433fc53f72630dc8c53851703dd440b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x101a58000 - 0x101a5ffff libswiftCoreMedia.dylib arm64  <c3d09cf9b972324da8df4037c9035d65> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
0x101a6c000 - 0x101a77fff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <6e35c3d115c2316c87b3dda8af5f1d72> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x101a8c000 - 0x101aa7fff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <e82a7f8230cf326ab53a424cf8e39570> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x101ad8000 - 0x101c33fff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <39002aaf2c42348780ab6eba82c171e1> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x101d80000 - 0x101d8bfff libswiftMediaPlayer.dylib arm64  <fdb5957c16f430dfb3ee37a59ebd0ddb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftMediaPlayer.dylib
0x101d98000 - 0x101d9ffff libswiftMetal.dylib arm64  <402fd36f302537ff93cdc58dca7ed35d> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
0x101dac000 - 0x101db3fff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <8ed77568c9ed3229ba7a6b0d92719402> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x101dc0000 - 0x101dc7fff libswiftQuartzCore.dylib arm64  <966ddd4d8a0330419d42a37268354104> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
0x101dd0000 - 0x101ddffff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <1194f49500ea38cbbcbae0ef1a3b0d14> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x101df4000 - 0x101e2ffff libswiftsimd.dylib arm64  <237ceb32eafd3d03b43598e851f96a92> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib
0x101e80000 - 0x101e87fff libswiftos.dylib arm64  <31302350f2a9398b9db789af41c9f6c8> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
0x101e94000 - 0x101e9bfff libswiftCoreData.dylib arm64  <01d77d6a3af93385a975824a71678146> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/CAE2BDB0-EB37-4A0D-93B7-0E2CD6347FBD/myAPPUS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib
0x1021a0000 - 0x1021abfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64  <a8cd788cc9113887ae254bd47d58c7c1> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x1b3dfa000 - 0x1b3dfbfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <b3dbcc8e41b03e51b7e65d2800dcdea9> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1b3dfc000 - 0x1b3e56fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <c406443c983a33829b164c441b7c2af4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1b3e57000 - 0x1b3e6afff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <311c3f6ae6de347a8f9d9be875f3c557> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1b3e6b000 - 0x1b45f3fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <823edfdc3149335c86f850561fec2c3c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1b45f4000 - 0x1b45f9fff libcache.dylib arm64  <e9bd17104b5e38658669ca9856df215b> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1b45fa000 - 0x1b4606fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  ...

EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `symbolicate` the crash log to get the exact details on the crashed line,

To get your symbolicated logs from Crash logs we need following files:

```
YourAppName.app — Application file (Executable).
YourAppName.app.dSYM — dSYM file, generated by XCODE when actual .app file complied. (optional)
YourAppName-Crash-log.crash — Crash log, that can be taken from the real device.
```

Move all the above files (`YourAppName.app, YourAppName.app.dSYM and YourAppName-Crash-log.crash`) into a Folder with a convenient name wherever you can go using Terminal easily.

So, move these three files into a folder `Crash` at `Desktop`.

Copy ‘symbolicatecrash' file from this location, and paste it to the `Desktop/Crash` from  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`

Then run the commands in `Terminal`,

1. cd Desktop/Crash — Press Enter
2. export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer" — Press Enter
3. ./symbolicatecrash -v YourAppName-Crash-log.crash YourAppName.app.dSYM — Press Enter

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated!